# Question about Maple.

Tags: math-software, maple

Let $s[1]:=\sum_{i=0}^{k} q^i$. In Maple, we use $sum(s[1], i..k)$ to compute $s$. There are two cases, namely $q=1$ or $q\neq 1$. I have to compute many such sums (s[1], s[2], ...) and have conditions $q\neq 1$. I need to compute $s[1]+s[2]+...$. How could I let $q\neq 1$ at the beginning (such that the value of $s[i]$ has only one case, not two cases $q=1$ or $q\neq 1$)? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [assume](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=assume) command.